# Cron job for a php artisan command

Tags: cron, laravel-artisan

When I usually run my commands I do it from `/var/www/project/html/current/` and it looks like this `php artisan import:myData`. This works great.

But I can't get it to work while running it as a cron job, I have tried the following cron jobs.

```
*/3 * * * 1-5 cd /var/www/project/html/current/ php artisan import:myData >/dev/null 2>&1

*/3 * * * 1-5 /var/www/project/html/current/ php artisan import:myData >/dev/null 2>&1

*/3 * * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/project/html/current/ php artisan import:myData >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

See here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

You add `* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` into your cron tab, which runs artisan schedule:run and then you add your console commands into the schedule Kernel with their schedule parameters, laravel handles the rest :)

From the docs:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
        })->daily();
    }
}
```

Edit:

You are also specifying an odd path to artisan, try:

```
*/3 * * * 1-5 cd /var/www/project/html/current/artisan import:myData >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Instead of

```
*/3 * * * 1-5 cd /var/www/project/html/current/ php artisan import:myData >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Hi, worth mentioning is that I am running my commands in Crontab. Shouldnt that be possible? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Is artisan supposed to be a directory? In /current/ I have an Artisan file, but not a directory. I might want to try to specify the full path for Crontab since /current/ is actually /releases/100 for example.

Comment: artisan is a php file without an extension, it sits in the root directory of Laravel. Does the /current/ directory ever exist on the server?

Comment: Edit: Full path seemed to have worked and without cd I believe. Thanks for your help ExohJosh!

Answer (score 4):

in the crontab add this job

```sh
*/3 * * * 1-5 cd /var/www/project/html/current && php artisan import:myData >/dev/null 2>&1
```

You forgot to put these characters "&&" between the path to your project folder and the artisan command

Example:

```sh
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504